# Extracting a substring using dot pattern in R

Tags: r

I have a string named rids.csf. I want to extract csf from it. How I can do it. I tried the following code but it did not work for me.

```
string<-"rids.csf"
sub(".","", string)
## outcome I got
"ids.csf"
## expected outcome
"csf"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can match characters (`.*`) till the `.` (escaped as `.` is a metacharacter) and replaced with blank (`""`_

```
sub(".*\\.", "", string)
#[1] "csf"
```

---

`.` in regex mode (by default it is `fixed = FALSE`) matches any character and because of that it matches the first character 'r' and removed it